# Rails - Destroy action in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have students, users (teachers) and lessons in my models.  A user has_many lessons as well as a teacher has_many lessons.  Of course each lesson belongs_to user and student.

Given this data association how can I use a destroy action to delete the lesson (invoked by a button)?

```
def destroy
    Lesson.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to lessons_path
end
```

My Schema

```
  create_table "lessons", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "cancelled"
    t.boolean  "late"
    t.boolean  "reschedule"
    t.integer  "room"
    t.string   "day"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
  end
```

The button that calls the action

```
<span><%= link_to 'Destroy', lessons_path, class: 'btn btn-danger' %></span>
```

Comment: What's not working? Can you share the error that you are getting? Also share the routes for `lessons` from `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use `resources :lessons` in your routes definition (generated by default by rails scaffold) and that maps destroy action to `DELETE` http verb, so you should use the proper verb (via `:method`) and also the correct url (passing a `Lesson` instance):

```
link_to 'Destroy', lesson_path(@lesson), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete
```

Comment: Yes, your assumption of my routes was correct.  Why does it map to the method: :delete instead of destroy?   This is REST by default?  BTW, I really appreciate everyone's help on here to answer my question

Comment: Check this link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have routes defined as `resources :lessons`, you could use the below link to destroy a particular `lesson`

```
<span><%= link_to 'Destroy', lesson_path(lesson), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' %></span>
```

where `lesson` (in `lesson_path(lesson)`) is an instance of `Lesson` model.
Also, you would need to specify **HTTP method DELETE** using `method: :delete` on the link so that the link routes to the correct `destroy` action in RESTful way.